# Spring Boot connection to AWS RDS MySQL - SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, ssl, amazon-rds

I have a Spring Boot application from which I am trying to connect to a MySQL on AWS RDS.
However I am having issues with the following error:

```
localhost-startStop-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
```

After enabling debug for the ssl handshake, I see that for the `CertificateRequest` step the `Cert Authorities:` are empty.
Based on my understanding this is the part where the **client** (spring boot app) needs to present a cert to the **server** (mysql db).

- `Certificate Request` step - The server will issue a certificate request from the client.
- The next step would be `*** Certificate chain`, which is the certificate the client is sending to the server.  In this case for me, it is sending the content of `keyStore_cert.jks`.

**What I think the issue so far:**
The server (mySQL db) does not know about this certificate (my keyStore_cert.jks) that the client (my app) is sending.
But, I was under the impression that the client certs are not required unless you set `REQUIRE X509` for the user.

**The questions:**

- Is there something else that I can look in order to find the exact problem?
- If the above is the issues, how can I fix it? How can I disable client verification?
- Or how can I keep client verification but have it work?
- Do I need add anything to the `keyStore_cert.jks`/`trustStore_cert.jks`?

---

---

**These are what my settings and what I have tried.**

- RDS Engine version: 5.7.22
- mysql-connector-java v8.0.13
- connection URL: `jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<db_name>?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true`
- for the user that I am using I executed the following on the DB:

```
ALTER USER '<my_db_user>'@'%' require SSL;
GRANT USAGE ON <db_name>.* TO '<my_db_user>'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
```

- Based on the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html): I imported those certs (root and intermediate) into the trustStore. Doing something: `keytool -import -keystore  trustStore_cert.jks -storepass <trustStore_password> -alias "awsrds-us-east1" -file rds-ca-2015-us-east-1.pem`
- I use our own keyStore. Nothing was done to the keyStore at this time.
- application trustStore and keyStore are passed as JVM param like the following:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path/keyStore_cert.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<keyStore_password>
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/trustStore_cert.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<trustStore_password>
```

- For the specific user, when I use MySQL Workbench and in the connection setting for **Use SSL** I specify: **If available** or **Require**. It connects with this message:

```
Host: <host>
Port: <port>
User: <user>
SSL: enabled with DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
```

- However if I specify, **Require and Verify CA** or **Require and Verify Identity** it gives this message: `SSL connection error: CA certificate is required if ssl-mode is VERIFY_CA or VERIFY_IDENTITY`. Which makes sense since i am not specifying anything for the CA file.

---

---

**Steps for the handshake (will omit some logs.):**

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.1 (seems okay)
***
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.1 (seems okay)
***
*** Certificate chain (has the root key)
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Seattle, O=Amazon.com, OU=RDS, CN=**<my_rds_name>abcd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com**
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
...
...
chain [1] = [ (has the us-east-1 key)
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Amazon RDS us-east-1 CA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
...
...
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Amazon RDS us-east-1 CA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
...
...
*** CertificateRequest (the Authorities are empty)
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>
*** ServerHelloDone
matching alias: <my keyStoreAlias>
*** Certificate chain (seems entries from my own key Store)
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=<the CN on my keyStore>, OU=Web Servers, O=Company , C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1.1 (seems okay)

*** CertificateVerify (seem okay)
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 50, 89, 33, 202, 193, 158, 226, 114, 128, 50, 198, 250 }
***
```

Comment: Did you get this resolved? facing similar issue "fatal alert: unknown_ca"

Comment: @user2677034 I did found a solution after engaging someone from AWS RDS support. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it works. I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After working with AWS RDS Support I got an explanation why the issue and how to fix it.

Just to clarify, this issue is mainly presented only if you pass your own keystore as part of JVM arguments.
Something like this:

```
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path/keyStore_cert.jks
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<keyStore_password>
```

RDS is a managed service and they do not have a way (currently) to load specific client certificates into the server.
Meaning they can’t pass a specific certificates in DB configuration level. Usually this would be possible if you were to standup your own MY SQL server. In the config file for that server you can specify the client/server certs. 
So, RDS can’t verify the certificate provided by client.

If you were to pass a keystore, which has a key-pair entry (as JVM argument or otherwise), during SSL handshake, the client authentications step would fail. This is expected behavior in database. RDS can’t restrict itself to verify (or not verify) the file loaded in client field for the client during the initial connection. So, if a keystore is passed, server will try to match the certificate keys with existing CA file and if doesn’t match it will not allow the connections.

The solution is to either not pass a keystore at all or pass a blank keystore (one that does not have a key-pair with just Trusted Certificate Entry or one that is just blank).

1. if you choose to not pass a keystore, then do not specify these properties 
   `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore= & -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=`. And construct the DB connection URL like this:
   `-Ddb_jdbc_url=jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<db_name>?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true`. You still need to provide the truststore. See at the bottom for more.
2. Pass a black keystore or (or pass the trust store in the keystore field)
   You can pass what ever you want for the keystore and trustore JVM params.
   And for the URL you construct it like this:

```
    -Ddb_jdbc_url=jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<db_name>?
    useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
    &clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/user/documents/projects/trust-store-rds.jks
    &clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=<password>
    &clientCertificateKeyStoreType=JKS
    &trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/user/documents/projects/trust-store-rds.jks
    &trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=<password>
    &trustCertificateKeyStoreType=JKS
```

Note that for both `trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl` and `clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl` I am passing the same file.

Note, you need to also configure all the previous steps:

1. enable SSL for a user on the DB.

```
CREATE USER 'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
ALTER USER 'my_user'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'my_user'@'%' REQUIRE SSL ;
```

2. You need to import the AWS Root and Regional certs into your truststore;
   Something like this:

```
     keytool -import -keystore trust-store-rds.jks -storepass changeit -noprompt alias "aws-rds-root" -file rds-ca-2015-root.pem

     keytool -import -keystore trust-store-rds.jks -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias "aws-rds-us-east-1" -file rds-ca-2015-us-east-1.pem
```

3. Build the URL as above.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 8.0.22 of the MySQL Connector/J driver you can now use the fallbackToSystemKeyStore property set to false to ignore any system level keystore rather than having to create a dummy one.

I've used this method successfully against an RDS MySQL 5.7 instance and where I initially saw the same "unknown_ca" error it now connects perfectly.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-security.html

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this issue - "Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca" while making connection with AWS RDS 8.X

This error came only when keystore was set at the JVM level. If only trustore is set at the JVM level and not the keystore, this issue do not pop up because truststore trusts RDS certificate already
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keystore_password

As RDS is shared service, there is no option in RDS to trust certificates of individual client. If keystore is passed, RDS thinks that the request is for 2 way SSL and it fails. On the other hand, we couldn't get rid of keystore at the JVM level because 2 way SSL was enabled with other backends such as API Gateway

Solution: we provided dummy keystore (trustore itself as it do not contain any private key) to the jdbc to override the keystore that was provided at the JVM level and it worked like a charm!!

public class MySQLSSLTest {

```
    private static final String DB_USER = "username";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "password";
    // This key store has only the prod root ca.
    private static final String KEY_STORE_FILE_PATH = "file-path-to-keystore";
    private static final String KEY_STORE_PASS = "keystore-password";
        
    public static void test(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", KEY_STORE_FILE_PATH);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", KEY_STORE_PASS);
        
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("user", DB_USER);
        properties.put("password", DB_PASSWORD);
        properties.put("sslMode", "DISABLED");
        properties.put("useSSL", "false");
        properties.put("clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl", "file:/path/to/your/trust/store");
        properties.put("clientCertificateKeyStorePassword", "truststore_password");
        properties.put("clientCertificateKeyStoreType", "jks");
        
 
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mydatabase.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306",properties);
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 1 from dual");
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
               try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
               }
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}

Hopefully this will help you!!!
```

Comment: your explanation makes sense but your code disables ssl and that may confuse others.